# Python (CSV/XLSX Editing) - If Column 'A' includes "string", then write "string_2" in Column B

Tags: python, pandas, string, openpyxl

Current outcome:

```
       *Email*                  *Organization*
m.ali@firstdomain.com            /Org: First
m.tyson@seconddomain.com         /Org: First
e.holyfield@firstdomain.com      /Org: First
```

Desired outcome:

```
       *Email*                  *Organization*
m.ali@firstdomain.com            /Org: First
m.tyson@seconddomain.com         /Org: Second
e.holyfield@firstdomain.com      /Org: First
```

Condition:

```
If a row in column('Email') contains the string('second'):
Replace the string in the same row, under column('Organization') with the string('/Org: Second')
```

Any way of doing this? Currently working with pandas to amend this csv.
I used the following to segregate one set of domains from the other:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=r'\s*,\s*', engine='python')
second_domains = df.loc[df['Email'].str.contains('second')]
```

But I don't know what else to do from here.

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `loc` assignment:

```
df.loc[df['Email'].str.contains('second'), 'Organization'] = '/Org: Second'
```

Comment: @TheCrazySwede Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)